# MediaElement.CurrentState retrieves System.Exception

Tags: c#, windows-10, c#-5.0, windows-10-mobile

I need to get the `CurrentState` from a `MediaElement` several times. I've created a simple function that looks like this:

```
    private string getCurrentState(MediaElement m)
    {
        return m.CurrentState.ToString();
    }
```

But everytime this function is called I get this:

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in MyProject but was not handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.
>
> (Exception gfrom HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RCP_E_WRONG_THREAD))

I've been investigating about this issue and, as I've understood, it usually comes when trying to retrieve the `CurrentState` before the `MediaOpened`event's been fired. Actually, this not suits my case since this function is called after that. However I call the `CurrentState`property I get the same exception and the weirdest thing of this all is that sometimes works, and sometimes not, so I definetely have got no idea of what is wrong in the code :S

Does anyone have any idea about how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get state from Non-ui thread. You should redesign you code to not interact with MediaElement from background thread (Task).
Or you can wrap getCurrentState method invocation into Despatcher

```
CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
<lambda for your code which should run on the UI thread>);
```